# NodeJs tcp server

Tags: node.js, tcp

i made i client tcp socket with c# and its work without any problem with c# server too

first before i send data to the client i sent the header contain the data length adn some other

now i tried same client code with nodeJs server TCP i got some issuse with Buffer size in nodeJs

first this is my header

```
 function writeInt(stream, int){
   var bytes = new Array(5)
   bytes[0] = 2
   bytes[1] = int >> 24
   bytes[2] = int >> 16
   bytes[3] = int >> 8
   bytes[4] = int
   bytes[5] = 0
 
   
   stream.write( Buffer.from(bytes))
  }
```

//1,2,3,4 the size of the buffer

if i want to send message to client i use

```
var buf = Buffer.from("HELLO THIS IS A MESSAGE FROM SERVER");
writeInt(sock, buf.length) 
sock.write(buf);
```

that's work because i use string but when i tried to send integer i got issuse

like

```
var buf = Buffer.from([1,2222,999,666]);
writeInt(sock, buf.length) 
sock.write(buf);
```

first thing the length of the buffer its wrong when i use `buf.length` it's return `4`!!

i tried other method found it in NodeJs website like

```
let buf = Buffer.alloc(3);  // Init buffer without writing all data to zeros
buf.writeUInt16BE(220);
```

and

```
let buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(2);
buf.writeUInt16BE(1234);
```

all those return wrong buffer length
or buffer length not like i sent with function `writeInt`

that's happen only with `Integer` when i sent string its work without any issuse

Comment: Buffers are a sequence of bytes (values 0-255).  Right from the [node.js Buffer doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) ***Buffer objects are used to represent a fixed-length sequence of bytes***.  If you want to put a number larger than 255 in a buffer, you have to break it into multiple bytes and you have to know what byte ordering you are using (big or little endian).  And, the consumer of your buffer on the other end of the socket has to know what format those bytes are in.

Comment: The Buffer API has methods for writing different sized numbers into the buffer with either endian format and you will have to allow for how many bytes it takes to store that particular number (1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes) depending upon whether it's a Uint8, Uint16, Uint32 or Uint64.

Comment: Also, your buffer length will be however long you allocated the buffer to be.  The length has nothing to do with how much you've written to the buffer.

Comment: @jfriend00 what about `var buf = Buffer.from([1,2222,999,666]);` 
`buf.length` return `4` why ? if i use string  `var buf = Buffer.from("hello");` 

this will return `5` but with first example its return wrong length

Comment: @jfriend00 i need to calculate the buffer size and send to client so i can read the buffer

Comment: I'd suggest you read the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_array) for `Buffer.from(array)`.  It explains it right there.  Hint, `Buffer.from(array)` takes an array of bytes (values 0-255).

Comment: You need to keep track of the length of the data you put in the Buffer and use that for the length or calculate that length ahead of time and allocate the buffer to the proper length.  Buffers don't grow like arrays.  They are a length of what you allocate them and do not change from that.  A Buffer is literally just a piece of memory you're putting data into.  The size of that memory block is what you allocated it to, no more, no less.